# Xamarin Eventhandler in viewmodel using MVVM helpers

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm, event-handling

What I would like to achieve is that when the user completes the Entry, it will uses that data to calculate another label. I have been using MVVM helpers for simple functions (not event handlers that I need the value of the entry) and it works nicely so I would like to use it here as well but it's not necessary.

First I will show a working basic function:

XAML:

```
<ImageButton x:Name="PlusButton" 
             Command="{Binding IncrementPrice}">
```

View-Model:

```
    public class ExistingProductPricingViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public ExistingProductPricingViewModel()
        {
            IncrementPrice = new MvvmHelpers.Commands.Command(OnIncrement);
        }

    public ICommand IncrementPrice { get; }
    double price = 0.0;
    string test = "Price";

    public string PriceTest
        {
            get => test;
            set => SetProperty(ref test, value);
        }

    void OnIncrement()
        {
            price++;
            PriceTest = $"{price}";
        }
```

This works, When I try it with EventHandler that I need the users input I can't get it to work. My last version of trying is as follows:

XAML:

```
<Entry x:Name="UpdatedCost"
       Completed="{Binding UpdatedCost_Dif}"/>
```

View-Model:

```
public class ExistingProductPricingViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
      public ExistingProductPricingViewModel()
      { //this is where I get the error
       UpdatedCost_Dif = new MvvmHelpers.Commands.Command(UpdatedCost_Completed(null,null));
      }
     
       public ICommand UpdatedCost_Dif { get; }
       int current_diff = 0;
       public string json = "2";

        public int PriceDifference
        {
            get => current_diff;
            set => SetProperty(ref current_diff, value);
        }

        private void UpdatedCost_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int updated = int.Parse(((Entry)sender).Text);
            current_diff = updated - int.Parse(json);
            PriceDifference = current_diff;
        }
```

The error I am getting is:

cannot convert from 'void' to 'System.Action'

It regards the line with UpdatedCost_Dif=... I have tried to split it into two different methods but that didn't work either. I would highly appreciate any help to understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Split into 2 methods, once for the button click one for the text entry. Both update the model independently, Completed is not a command, it's an event. So bind it to the event handler instead

Comment: Thank you, I have updated my question since I am getting the error I got when trying to split it into two functions.

Comment: you can bind commands, but you cannot bind event handlers.  You can use EventToCommandBehavior to translate and event into a command.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass a parameter in the command method, you need to add "CommandParameter" to pass it.
Check this link for more information:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/button#using-the-command-interface